# Error running 'app': Default Activity not found in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lIYP.png)

i am trying to change my launcher activity .i tried this.wanted to have Welcome as my launcher activity

Comment: Please dont just post images, but copy paste the code in this question. 
Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
    ...
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```